# How to get confusion matrix when using flow_from_directory?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

i have faced some problem on how could i create the confusion matrix to calculate the TP/TN/FP/FN/Recals/Acc to evaluate this model . How can i extract a confusion matrix after compiling and fitting this model ? And thank you.

```
# Forming datasets
datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255, validation_split=0.3)
# Training and validation dataset
train1 = datagen.flow_from_directory('C:/Users/hamza/Desktop/kkk/TrainD', seed=123, subset='training')
val = datagen.flow_from_directory('C:/Users/hamza/Desktop/kkk/TrainD', seed=123, subset='validation')


# Test dataset for evaluation
datagen2 = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)

test = datagen2.flow_from_directory('C:/Users/hamza/Desktop/kkk/TestD')


from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print('Confusion Matrix\n')
print(confusion)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to save it in a file ? You can save it in a callback. Either as an image that you could save in png, or in a text file.

Comment: I  want to plot it  . and  then i wan to  calculate  the  metrics  (TP? TN? FP? FN? and others

Answer (score 0):

Hou can use the example from [here](https://github.com/chasingbob/keras-visuals/blob/master/visual_callbacks.py) I modified it slightly to save the result in png

```py
from keras.callbacks import Callback
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches  
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import itertools
import numpy as np

class ConfusionMatrixPlotter(Callback):
    """Plot the confusion matrix on a graph and update after each epoch
    # Arguments
        X_val: The input values 
        Y_val: The expected output values
        classes: The categories as a list of string names
        normalize: True - normalize to [0,1], False - keep as is
        cmap: Specify matplotlib colour map
        title: Graph Title
    """
    def __init__(self, X_val, Y_val, classes, normalize=False, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, title='Confusion Matrix'):
        self.X_val = X_val
        self.Y_val = Y_val
        self.title = title
        self.classes = classes
        self.normalize = normalize
        self.cmap = cmap
        plt.ion()
        #plt.show()
        plt.figure()

        plt.title(self.title)
        
        

    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        pass

    
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):    
        plt.clf()
        pred = self.model.predict(self.X_val)
        max_pred = np.argmax(pred, axis=1)
        max_y = np.argmax(self.Y_val, axis=1)
        cnf_mat = confusion_matrix(max_y, max_pred)
   
        if self.normalize:
            cnf_mat = cnf_mat.astype('float') / cnf_mat.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]

        thresh = cnf_mat.max() / 2.
        for i, j in itertools.product(range(cnf_mat.shape[0]), range(cnf_mat.shape[1])):
            plt.text(j, i, cnf_mat[i, j],                                          
                         horizontalalignment="center",
                         color="white" if cnf_mat[i, j] > thresh else "black")

        plt.imshow(cnf_mat, interpolation='nearest', cmap=self.cmap)

        # Labels
        tick_marks = np.arange(len(self.classes))
        plt.xticks(tick_marks, self.classes, rotation=45)
        plt.yticks(tick_marks, self.classes)

        plt.colorbar()
                                                                                                         
        plt.tight_layout()                                                    
        plt.ylabel('True label')                                              
        plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
                                         
        # Save the figure to PNG
        plt.savefig(f"confusion_matrix_epoch={epoch}.png")
```

This will save one matrix per epoch with the epoch number in the file name.
Now, I am not sure how you would want to plot the TP / TN / FP / FN / Recal / Acc on that matrix, I personally would just add them in the **metrics** argument of the **model.fit** method that you use to fit your neural network.